# Storing p values using Econometrics toolbox in matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop

This code will run with the econometrics toolbox,

```
    model = arima('Constant',0.5,'AR',{0.9999},'Variance',.4);
rng('default')
Y = simulate(model,50);
figure
plot(Y)
xlim([0,50])
title('Simulated AR(1) Process')

rng('default')
Y = simulate(model,50,'NumPaths',1000);
Y1=Y(:,1);

for ii = 1:50
Mdl = arima(1,0,0);
EstMdl = estimate(Mdl, [Y(:,ii)]);
end
```

How can I store the p-values from the EstMdl for each iteration (i.e. a vector with 5 pvalues) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`summarize`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/arima.summarize.html) (requires ≥ R2018a) to get the results of [`estimate`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/arima.estimate.html).

Showing the results for one iteration here:

```
>> ii=1;
>> Mdl = arima(1,0,0);
>> EstMdl = estimate(Mdl, [Y(:,ii)]);

    ARIMA(1,0,0) Model (Gaussian Distribution):

                 Value     StandardError    TStatistic      PValue  
                _______    _____________    __________    __________

    Constant     622.14        427.99         1.4536         0.14605
    AR{1}       0.87561      0.085586         10.231      1.4432e-24
    Variance    0.37122      0.079507          4.669      3.0263e-06

>> Results = summarize(EstMdl);
>> PValues = Results.Table.PValue

PValues =

    0.1460
    0.0000
    0.0000
```

Comment: Thanks, a big help, but is there a way to get the P-value for just the AR{1} coefficient for each for loop

Comment: @Tony  `PValuesAR1(ii) = Results.Table.PValue(2)` since `AR{1}` is the second row here.  Remember to preallocate `PValuesAR1`