# How to convert a standard error to p-value in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am estimating a regression in MATLAB long hand.

I've got the standard error and coefficient, is there any quick way to get the p-value in MATLAB?

Any tips or tricks would be appreciated?

Comment: Is this an implementation question or a statistics/math question? Do you know how to convert std into p-value outside MATLAB, and are just struggling with the MATLAB implementation? Take a look at the docs of [`nbintest`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/nbintest.html), maybe it'll point you in the right direction.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing p values using Econometrics toolbox in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54091862/storing-p-values-using-econometrics-toolbox-in-matlab)

Comment: Not a duplicate as that is with the Econometrics toolbox, this is long hand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually p-values are from a statistical test, to check the statistical significance of the result, using t-test for example.